# How to select a certain element that is closest to the end of a given div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have a div called `the_div`. In this div there will be multiple submit buttons. The submit buttons are added dynamically on the page.

```
<div id="the_div">
    ...other stuff
    <input type='submit' value='Add'>
    ...other stuff
    <input type='submit' value='Add'>
    ...other stuff
    <input type='submit' value='Add'> -need to select this one
</div>
```

Is there a way I can use a jQuery selector to select the submit button that is closest to the end of the div? In the example above it would be the third submit button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [last](http://api.jquery.com/last).

`$('#the_div :submit:last')...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#the_div').find('input:submit').eq(-1)
```

This will select the last submit inside `#the_div`. `eq()` gives you allot of control. If you want to select the first submit you can do `eq(0)`, or before last you can do `eq(-2)`

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/cvcHf/

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY LIKE THIS

```
$("#THE_DIV").closest() or $('#the_div').find('input:submit').eq(':last');
```

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT WAS NOT WORKING.. TH